# C programming, [Error] called object 'swap' is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I need to do a program that lists three ages from lowest to highest, then highest to lowest, using pointers.  Whenever I try to compile, the compiler keeps giving the error "[Error] called object 'swap' is not a function or function pointer".  Didn't I declare this correctly before the function that I stated it in though? I am having problems at the "swap (*p1, *p2, *p3);"

I am guessing that I just don't know how to transfer pointers across functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 70
#define MIN 0

void swap (int*p1, int*p2, int*p3)
{
   int temp;

   *p1 == temp;
   *p1 == *p2;
   *p2 == temp;

   printf ("%d %d %d", *p2, *p3, *p1);
}

void leasttogreatest (age1, age2, age3)
{
   int *p1,*p2,*p3;
   int swap;

   if (age1 < age2 && age2 < age3)
   {
      printf ("%d %d %d\n", age1, age2, age3);
      *p1 == age1;
      *p2 == age3;
      *p3 == age2;
   }
   else if (age1<age3 && age3<age2)
   {  
      printf ("%d %d %d\n", age1, age3, age2);
      *p1 == age1;
      *p2 == age2;
      *p3 == age3;
   }
   else if (age2<age1 && age1<age3)
   {
      printf ("%d %d %d\n", age2, age1, age3);
      *p1 == age2;
      *p2 == age3;
      *p3 == age1;
   }
   else if (age2<age3 && age3<age1)
   {
      printf ("%d %d %d\n", age2, age3, age1);
      *p1 == age2;
      *p2 == age1;
      *p3 == age3;
   }
   else if (age3<age1 && age1<age2)
   {
      printf ("%d %d %d\n", age3, age1, age2);
      *p1 == age3;
      *p2 == age2;
      *p3 == age1;
   }
   else if (age3<age2 && age2<age1)
   {
      printf ("%d %d %d\n", age3, age2, age1);
      *p1 == age3;
      *p2 == age1;
      *p3 == age2;
   }
   swap (*p1, *p2, *p3);
}

int main (void)
{
   int age1, age2, age3;
   char choice;

   do
   {
      do
      {
         printf ("Enter 3 Student ages to sort (0-70): ");
         scanf ("%d %d %d", &age1, &age2, &age3);
         getchar ();
         if (age1<MIN||age2<MIN||age3<MIN||age1>MAX||age2>MAX||age3>MAX)
            printf ("ERR:  Student ages out of range(0-70)!\n\n");
      } while (age1<MIN||age2<MIN||age3<MIN||age1>MAX||age2>MAX||age3>MAX);

      leasttogreatest (age1, age2, age3);


      printf ("Want to sort more Student ages? ");
      scanf ("%c", &choice);
      getchar ();

   }while (choice != 'n');
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is compiler switch -Wall, if you are using gcc, use it and see what else may need attention.

Comment: Why does your `swap` function ` take 3 arguments? You repeatedly use `==` where you need `=`. Even fixing that, the logic of your `swap` function is incorrect.

Comment: The equality operations (instead of assignments) are peculiar (read 'pointless because nothing changes as a result of executing them').

Comment: Note that the function definition `void leasttogreatest (age1, age2, age3)` is using a non-prototype, K&R style declaration with implicit `int` as the type of the arguments.  This is extremely bad style in any code written in this millennium; it wasn't great code if written in the last five years of the previous millennium.  The C99 standard formally made the notation obsolete, though many compilers still allow it by default, but it was not good style even according to the C89/C90 standard (though it was legitimate). It should be `void leasttogreatest (int age1, int age2, int age3)`.

Comment: Also note that even if the code like `*p3 == age2;` is modified to `*p3 = age2;`, it is assigning to the value pointed at by an uninitialized pointer.  You may have had `p3 = &age2;` in mind instead.  Even assuming you remove the `int swap;` definition, the function call `swap (*p1, *p2, *p3);` is passing three `int` values to a function that expects `int` pointers.  You'd need to write `swap(p1, p2, p3);`.  I note that your code in `swap()` should not print too; the function would have to be renamed `swap_and_print()`, or the printing should be done in the calling code.

Comment: Your code is not going to be happy if it encounters EOF.

Comment: when using the scanf() function, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 2):

In the function `leasttogreatest`, you create an integer named "swap" too. This is not valid.

Comment: Strictly, the local variable `swap` is entirely valid but hides the function `swap()` so you cannot call the function from within `leasttogreatest()`.  It is ill-advised (especially since the variable `swap` is otherwise unused) rather than 'not valid'.  The problem would be diagnosed if the code was compiled with GCC and the `-Wshadow` flag.

Answer (score 2):

Several things wrong:

1) Using "==" instead of "=".  You also need the "assign to" the variable on the *left* (not vice versa).

```
// Corrected example
void swap (int *p1, int *p2, int *p3)
{
   int temp;

   temp = *p1;
   *p1 = *p2;
   *p2 = temp;
   // No - I have no idea what you put "p3" there for...
   printf ("%d %d %d", *p2, *p3, *p1);
}
```

2) You define "swap" as a variable, then use it as a function.  Just delete the line "int swap;"

3) You defined "swap()" as accepting three integer pointers ... then you try to use it by passing three "int's".  Hence the compiler error.  Do this instead:

```
void leasttogreatest (age1, age2, age3)
{
   int i1, i2, i3
   // int swap; <-- Delete this line

   if (age1 < age2 && age2 < age3)
   {
      printf ("%d %d %d\n", age1, age2, age3);
      i1 = age1;
      ...
   swap (&i1, &i2, &i3);
```

I suspect there are other problems, but hopefully this will help...

Answer (score 1):

I can trace out 2 bugs in this program at a glance:

1. `int swap;` as a variable and there is also a function called swap() so that the compiler gets confused and it refers to variable swap instead of calling function swap();
2. `*p1 == age3;` has to be replaced by `*p1 = age3;` if you want to assign a value

Comment: The compiler is not confused; the programmer might be.  You can't call an `int` variable — it isn't a function.  By defining a local variable `swap`, the function `swap()` is hidden in the function `leasttogreatest()`.  It's a bad idea to write the code like that, especially as the variable seems to be unused.  But it is the programmer, not the compiler, that is confused.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing to add to all the above answers.

```
 *p1 == age1;
 *p2 == age3;
 *p3 == age2;
```

should be corrected as

```
 *p1 = age1;
 *p2 = age3;
 *p3 = age2;
```

But before doing that, **these pointers should point to valid memory location.**

Comment: FYI, that's part of what I tried to say.  Look at "i1" etc in my example above

Comment: @paulsm4 Yup missed it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Swap is an int and you can't cast the three pointers into a single int.  Make a function that can cast three ints and print them and you will be good.